# Cannot store dictionary or object in request session in django view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-sessions

I am trying to set a session in one view and read this session in another view. Trying to store a dictionary in session.

```
request.session['staffdict'] = staffdict
```

When i try to get dictionary from the session in second view :

```
staffdict = request.session.get('staffdict')
```

I get below error :

> Django Version:   2.2.6
>   Exception Type: TypeError
>   Exception Value:
>   Object of type 'UUID' is not JSON serializable
>   Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in default, line 180
>   Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
>   Python Version: 3.6.8

Answer (score 2):

I use pickle's dumps() and loads() functions, and convert the bytes objects from these methods to/from hex like so:

```
import pickle
dict = {'s':'string', 'i':1}
hexdict = pickle.dumps(dict).hex()

# the above hexdict should be JSON OK

dict2 = pickle.loads(bytes.fromhex(hexdict))
print(dict2)
```

Comment: For using pickle there is build in serializer `serializers.PickleSerializer`.
But pickle may not work with all session backends

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota that is why I use the hex conversion in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You got response in error message. With your settings django serialize object to json and your dictionary contains non object which has no rule for serialize. 
[documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization)

I suggest to read also [Write your own serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#write-your-own-serializer). Then you can write something like this.

```py
import uuid
import json

class SerializeUUIDEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, uuid.UUID):
            return {"__uuid__": True, "val": str(obj)}
        return super().default(o)


def serialize_hook(dkt: dict):
    if "__uuid__" in dkt:
        return uuid.UUID(dkt["val"])
    return dkt


class OwnSerilizer:
    def dumps(self, obj):
        return json.dumps(obj, cls=SerializeUUIDEncoder).encode('latin-1')

    def loads(self, data):
        return json.loads(data.decode('latin-1'), object_hook=serialize_hook)
```

this code use standard argument of json library methods. You can read more in [dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) documentation and in [load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Django 3+, this seems to work for me...

```py
request.session['cart'] = {}
```